# JS Upload image from Canvas without "toDataURL" method

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to upload image from canvas to the server. The common solution is to get data from canvas using `toDataURL` method but unfortunately some images leads Chrome to crush. I was trying to use `image/png` and `image/jpeg` mime types, I was also trying to reduce quality for `image/jpeg` up to 0.4 but Chrome (vesrion 45.0.2454.85 m) was crushing anyway. Is there any way to extract image from cavnas without this method, like retrieving Blob object or something like this?

Comment: Never found a solution to this eh?

Comment: Fortunately, I don't get crashes anymore, seems like later chrome versions fixed the original issue

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the images are too big, and chrome fails with an Out of memory crash. Maybe your solution is reduce the quality of the images returning it in JPEG.

```
 var fullQuality = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
 var mediumQuality = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
 var lowQuality = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.1);
```

You can try too the image format `image/webp` special in chrome.

Good luck.

### EDIT

You've got the method `toBlob()` available too, if you need to change the logic:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
  var newImg = document.createElement("img"),
      url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  newImg.onload = function() {
    // no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };

  newImg.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(newImg);
});
```

### EDIT 2

According to MDN website, you have a polyfill.

```
if (!HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob) {
 Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toBlob', {
  value: function (callback, type, quality) {

    var binStr = atob( this.toDataURL(type, quality).split(',')[1] ),
        len = binStr.length,
        arr = new Uint8Array(len);

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++ ) {
     arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    callback( new Blob( [arr], {type: type || 'image/png'} ) );
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: I've already tried to reduce image quality up to 0.4 and it didn't help. And 0.1 is too low quality. I've tried your advice to use `image/webp` type and sometimes it still crashes on some images. As for the `toBlob` method, Chrome doesn't support it =/
The image size is 1200x600 and dataUrl string length for `image/webp` is around 70000 so it doesn't look like "out of memory" crash

Comment: You have a polyfill to compatibilize with chrome. See edit.

Comment: But the polyfill is based on the same `toDataURL` method, so it still doesn't solve the issue =/

Comment: There are things that you can't make in a web browser context. If chrome has this bug, you can't workaround it. You must to change the logic, or the functionality, or avoid to use the functionality with this browser.

Comment: I see. I was hoping that it's possible to implement the same logic without using this particular function

Comment: I don't know if you achieve it, but I wish good luck for you!